# Infinite do while loop

Tags: java, loops, do-while

For some reason, my loop never ends, despite specifically assigning the value read by the scanner by the user. When user types 0, it goes on

```
public static void InseretToDB() throws IOException {
    IO init = new IO();
    Scanner scan = init.getScanner();
    BufferedWriter bWriter = init.getWriter();
    int j;

    do {
        System.out.println("Name");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        bWriter.write(name);
        bWriter.write("      ");
        System.out.println("Ocuppation");
        String occupation = scan.nextLine();
        bWriter.write(occupation);
        bWriter.newLine();
        System.out.println(" Input 1 to continue, 0 to end");
        j = (int) Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } while (j != 0);

}
```

Comment: Your loop will end when `j = 0`...

Comment: Where do you call the `InseretToDB` method?

Comment: inside of the switch statement in the main class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initalize the scanner as

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Replace current code from

```
j = (int) Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

To

```
try{
    j = scan.nextInt();
}catch(Exception e){
   j = -1;
}
```

Comment: Using the scanner without defining the charset worked for some reason. Those are some serious shenanigans! Note to self - don't change charset when you input numbers in the future

Answer (score 0):

The loop did end when I typed 0, but I changed the program to the following

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
```

Hope this helps,